# Is there a strict way of validating an AVRO schema against data?

Tags: java, avro

I'm trying to build a system that requires data validation against Avro schemas. As it is, I'm using the following to validate:

```
DatumReader reader = new GenericDatumReader(schema);
Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(schema, data);
ValidatingDecoder validatingDecoder = DecoderFactory.get().validatingDecoder(schema, decoder);
reader.read(null, validatingDecoder);
```

being the schema:

```
"{"
          + "  \"namespace\": \"com.myApp.events\","
          + "  \"type\": \"record\","
          + "  \"name\": \"CityPeriodEvent\","
          + "  \"fields\": ["
          + "    { \"name\": \"cityCode\", \"type\": \"string\" },"
          + "    { \"name\": \"periodId\", \"type\": \"long\" },"
          + "    { \"name\": \"startTime\",  \"type\": {\"type\": \"long\", \"logicalType\": \"timestamp-millis\"} },"
          + "    { \"name\": \"finishTime\",  \"type\": {\"type\": \"long\", \"logicalType\": \"timestamp-millis\"} },"
          + "    { \"name\": \"currency\", \"type\": [\"null\", \"string\"], \"default\": null },"
          + "    { \"name\": \"habitants\", \"type\": \"long\" }"
          + "  ]"
          + "}";
```

correct data configuration:

```
"{\"cityCode\": \"BCN\", \"periodId\": 3, \"startTime\": 500, \"finishTime\": 3000, \"currency\": {\"string\":\"eur\"}, \"habitants\": 10000";
```

incorrect data configuration:

```
"{\"cityCode\": \"BCN\", \"periodId\": 3, \"startTime\": 500, \"finishTime\": 3000, \"currency\": {\"string\":\"eur\"}, \"habitants\": 10000, \"someAdditional\": 3}";
```

(notice that the incorrect one has an additional field at the end).

The problem is that both of these configurations validate as correct, whereas I only want the first one to be, so I'm looking for a very strict validation.

From what I've read in the documentation,  the DatumReader.read function does a DFS through the schema, comparing the leaves of the schema against the fields of the data configuration file. This results on it ignoring the extra fields, since the comparison is unidirectional.

Is there some way to make this more strict? I've been doing research and trying out different things, but none seem to work. I don't think I'm looking for something very specific, I think lots of systems would want this so I think I'm just missing something.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. I'd suggest you simplify your question to make a minimal example (1 field in the schema, 2 fields in the wrong json) so it is easier to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have found, this function is available in [Apache Nifi ValidateRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.17.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ValidateRecord/index.html), see "Allow Extra Fields".

> If the incoming data has fields that are not present in the schema, this property determines whether or not the Record is valid. If true, the Record is still valid. If false, the Record will be invalid due to the extra fields.

Additionally, this functionality was recently added to `fastavro` implementation in Python.

```py
from io import BytesIO
from fastavro import writer, parse_schema

schema_json = {
    "type": "record",
    "name": "test",
    "fields": [{"name": "id", "type": "string"}]
}
data_json = {"id": "test", "query": "test"}

parsed_schema = parse_schema(schema_json)
writer(BytesIO(), parsed_schema, [data_json], strict_allow_default=True)
```

`ValueError: record contains more fields than the schema specifies: query`